# How to kill a proccess that run in port from zsh terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, zsh, ubuntu-20.04

I run nodejs server in port 3333

How can I kill the process / terminal that run the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:3333)
```

Comment: you shouldn't need sudo for kill or lsof